# Search page shows empty fields of unpublished content

Tags: views, search

How can I make a filter to my search page that hides unpublished content?

In filter criteria I only have global, indexed and search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view, besides FILTER click on add, select Content Published (YES)

Comment: I'm using a search api, and therefore I dont have content as an option. I only have global, indexed and search.

Comment: hummm... in RELATIONSHIP can you add a relationship of node/article?

Comment: indexed node yes....

Comment: try adding that and then see if now lets you filter by published

Comment: where should I be able to add "by published" after this?

Comment: in FILTER CRITERIA click add and search for "Published"

Comment: no nothing....just global and indexed

Comment: bummer, hopefully someone else knows the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the effort! Seems the solution was what you suggested, but it was only available through the search api module :)